# the javascript for dragging and dropping not loading - drupal 7

Tags: javascript

for some reason when I add new modules the tabledrag.js is not loading.  Tried taking the modules out, clearing cache several times.  Aggregated js as well.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing http://www.drupal.org/project/speedy

it minifies core javascript files